# sql query error using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tb_users INNER JOIN tb_ph ON tb_ph.username=tb_users.username WHERE tb_ph.r' at line 1

I get this error above when trying to run the query below

```
UPDATE tb_users 
   SET tb_users.tgh = tb_ph.readygh,
       tb_users.readygh = tb_ph.readygh * 0.25,
       tb_users.profitbalance = tb_ph.readygh - (tb_ph.readygh * 0.25) 
FROM tb_users 
INNER JOIN tb_ph ON tb_ph.username=tb_users.username 
WHERE tb_ph.readygh = tb_ph.paket + (tb_ph.paket*0.6) 
    and tb_users.username=tb_ph.username
```

How can it be sorted out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax in MySQL is:

```
UPDATE tb_users u INNER JOIN
       tb_ph p
       ON p.username = u.username 
    SET u.tgh = p.readygh,
        u.readygh = p.readygh * 0.25, 
        u.profitbalance = p.readygh - (p.readygh * 0.25) 
WHERE p.readygh = p.paket + (p.paket*0.6);
```

Notes:

- Your syntax is SQL Server syntax, not MySQL syntax.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- There is no need to repeat the join condition in both the `ON` clause and the `WHERE` clause.
- The `WHERE` condition is highly suspicious.  Normally, you don't use equality on floating point values, because very small rounding errors could make "equal" values fail an equality comparison.